# Relation between current voltage .Acc. to ohm's law and P=IV

Tags: voltage, power, current, resistance

[image]

Here in image increase in current increase the voltage and vice versa

[image]

Here in image when voltage increase current low and vice versa 2 pages of same books what is right and how to understand ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relation between current, resistance and voltage according to Ohm's law, Joules law of heat and P=IV](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472959/relation-between-current-resistance-and-voltage-according-to-ohms-law-joules)

Comment: Please don't cross-post

Comment: The answers gave me new knowledge but my doubt could not be clarified so I posted the question more clearly with specific images .I am sorry if it had caused any inconvenience .I am very new to this community .

Answer (score 1):

Note first of all that the resistance of an incandescent light bulb is **not** constant. The resistance of the filament increases significantly as the filament temperature increases, so the resistance of a cold bulb is much less than the resistance of a hot bulb.

Now the first question specifies that the voltage will only change **marginally**, which is a way of saying that the temperature of the bulb won't change much. So, for this question and in these specific circumstances, we assume that the resistance of the bulb does not change. Therefore, Ohm's Law (\$V = R \times I\$) says that current **through the bulb** and voltage **across the bulb** will be proportional...as one goes up the other must go up.

The second question involves **Watt's Law**, \$P = V \times I\$. The power consumed by an element is equal to the current through the element times the voltage across the element. If we assume that the amount of power consumed is constant, as this question does, then we now see that as the voltage goes up the current must go down.

The difference between the two cases is that one assumes constant **resistance** and the other assumes constant **power**.

Comment: So what actually happens on an increase in voltage does the current increase or decrease .Does more charge flow per second or less .

Comment: When potential difference between two points increase then more charge should flow per second as push has increased . Therefore more current ,as current is charge flow per second .Is this correct ?

Comment: If the voltage is applied to a constant **resistance** then an increase in voltage will cause an increase in current. If the voltage is producing constant **power** then an increase in current must come with a decrease in current.

Answer (score 0):

The text in these 2 images are just referring to the inherent nature of Ohms law.

The light bulb has a fixed resistance.  So if the voltage supplied is higher, the current draw will be higher, yielding a brighter light.  If the supplied voltage is lower than the rating, the current draw will be lower than the previous case and the light will be dimmer.

In the 2nd text.  Power is constant.  With a constant power, changing either one of the voltage/current parameters will yield a change in the other parameter.